# Why java Graphics drawImage first time is slow

Tags: java, performance, graphics

I want to mix some images in `java.awt.Graphics`, so I write utils to do that. I find it is so slow to call the `graphics.drawImage()`; the first time, it takes 2 seconds. I think there is something that needs to be initialized, and it is very slow.

So I ran a benchmark to find the reason, and I get a result like this, I find the step3 call in the first time is slow, I find every thread first time will slow.
I will keep going.

```
StopWatch '0': running time (millis) = 1631
-----------------------------------------
ms     %     Task name
-----------------------------------------
00005  000%  create canvas
00095  006%  draw picture
00003  000%  step 1
00025  002%  step 2
01373  084%  step 3
00000  000%  step 4
00000  000%  step 5
00130  008%  save picture

StopWatch '2': running time (millis) = 1632
-----------------------------------------
ms     %     Task name
-----------------------------------------
00005  000%  create canvas
00093  006%  draw picture
00004  000%  step 1
00022  001%  step 2
01378  084%  step 3
00000  000%  step 4
00000  000%  step 5
00130  008%  save picture

StopWatch '1': running time (millis) = 1633
-----------------------------------------
ms     %     Task name
-----------------------------------------
00005  000%  create canvas
00095  006%  draw picture
00003  000%  step 1
00031  002%  step 2
01370  084%  step 3
00000  000%  step 4
00000  000%  step 5
00129  008%  save picture

StopWatch '1': running time (millis) = 115
-----------------------------------------
ms     %     Task name
-----------------------------------------
00001  001%  create canvas
00000  000%  draw picture
00000  000%  step 1
00005  004%  step 2
00000  000%  step 3
00000  000%  step 4
00000  000%  step 5
00109  095%  save picture

StopWatch '0': running time (millis) = 123
-----------------------------------------
ms     %     Task name
-----------------------------------------
00001  001%  create canvas
00000  000%  draw picture
00000  000%  step 1
00009  007%  step 2
00000  000%  step 3
00000  000%  step 4
00000  000%  step 5
00113  092%  save picture

StopWatch '2': running time (millis) = 127
-----------------------------------------
ms     %     Task name
-----------------------------------------
00001  001%  create canvas
00000  000%  draw picture
00000  000%  step 1
00014  011%  step 2
00000  000%  step 3
00000  000%  step 4
00000  000%  step 5
00112  088%  save picture

StopWatch '1': running time (millis) = 116
-----------------------------------------
ms     %     Task name
-----------------------------------------
00000  000%  create canvas
00001  001%  draw picture
00000  000%  step 1
00004  003%  step 2
00000  000%  step 3
00000  000%  step 4
00000  000%  step 5
00111  096%  save picture

StopWatch '0': running time (millis) = 113
-----------------------------------------
ms     %     Task name
-----------------------------------------
00001  001%  create canvas
00000  000%  draw picture
00001  001%  step 1
00004  004%  step 2
00000  000%  step 3
00000  000%  step 4
00000  000%  step 5
00107  095%  save picture

StopWatch '2': running time (millis) = 111
-----------------------------------------
ms     %     Task name
-----------------------------------------
00001  001%  create canvas
00000  000%  draw picture
00000  000%  step 1
00006  005%  step 2
00000  000%  step 3
00000  000%  step 4
00000  000%  step 5
00104  094%  save picture
```

I tested many times, and the results are the same.

**My benchmark code:**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.springframework.util.StopWatch;

public class ImageTest {

  static final Font roman = new Font("inherit", Font.PLAIN, 40);
  static final String basePath = "/Users/shiheng/Desktop/";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(basePath, "download.jpeg"));
    final BufferedImage overlay = ImageIO.read(new File(basePath, "images.jpeg"));
    List<Thread> threadList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      final int id = i;
      Runnable runnable = () -> {
        try {
          for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            benchmark(id, j, basePath, image, overlay);
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      };
      Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
      thread.start();
      threadList.add(thread);
    }
    for (Thread thread : threadList) {
      thread.join();
    }
  }

  static void mark(StopWatch stopWatch, String note) {
    if (stopWatch.isRunning()) {
      stopWatch.stop();
    }
    stopWatch.start(note);
  }

  static void benchmark(int id, int i, String basePath, BufferedImage image, BufferedImage overlay)
      throws Exception {
    StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch(String.valueOf(id));

    mark(stopWatch, "create canvas");
    int w = Math.max(image.getWidth(), overlay.getWidth());
    int h = Math.max(image.getHeight(), overlay.getHeight());
    BufferedImage combined = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    mark(stopWatch, "draw picture");
    int cw = overlay.getWidth() / 4 * 3;
    int ch = overlay.getHeight() / 4 * 3;
    ImageUtil imageUtil = ImageUtil.getInstance(combined);
    mark(stopWatch, "step 1");
    imageUtil.drawImage(image, i, i);
    mark(stopWatch, "step 2");
    imageUtil.drawImage(overlay.getScaledInstance(cw, ch, Image.SCALE_FAST), i, i);
    mark(stopWatch, "step 3");
    imageUtil.drawText("意大利炮!", 23 + i, 100 + i, roman, Color.PINK);
    mark(stopWatch, "step 4");
    imageUtil.drawText("意大利炮!", 29 + i, 100 + i, roman, Color.BLUE);
    mark(stopWatch, "step 5");
    imageUtil.drawText("意大利炮!", 26 + i, 100 + i, roman, Color.WHITE);

    mark(stopWatch, "save picture");
    ImageIO.write(combined, "PNG", new File(basePath, "combined.png"));
    stopWatch.stop();
    System.out.println(stopWatch.prettyPrint());
  }

}
```

**My util code:**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class ImageUtil {

  private final Graphics graphics;
  private final BufferedImage canvas;

  private ImageUtil(BufferedImage canvas) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.graphics = canvas.getGraphics();
  }

  public static ImageUtil getInstance(BufferedImage canvas) {
    return new ImageUtil(canvas);
  }

  public ImageUtil drawText(String text, int x, int y, Font font, Color color) {
    graphics.setFont(font);
    graphics.setColor(color);
    graphics.drawString(text, x, y);
    return this;
  }

  public ImageUtil drawImage(Image image, int x, int y) {
    graphics.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
    return this;
  }

}
```

I want to find the resource that needs to be initialized so I can initialize it by hand.

Comment: Run it 10, 000+ times to let the JIT keep in, then perform your timings

Comment: Image loading takes time (basic I/O), loading fonts can take time, depending on the implementation, the underlying graphics pipeline can take time. I'd move the image loading and font creation out of the loop and start with that

Comment: thank you, I edit my code and try it again, it is the same, it is a good idea, I will move everything out step by step.